# Build a time elapse function

Tags: shell-script, bash-functions

i want to build a time elapse function inside a script to print that time every second for example the output should look like below:

```
finding files inside a directory
time elapse HH:MM:SS
```

- HH is hour
- MM is minute
- SS is second

and the line time elapse etc keeps counting up 1 second on the screen without printing a new line
after the script is finished executing the function stops.

Comment: OK, so what part of it is giving you trouble? What do you have so far? What works? What doesn't work? Please [edit] your question and  show us your code so we don't give you information you already have.

Comment: i can echo the date like this date '+%H%M%S' but how can i count up the seconds

Comment: As I said before, please ***[edit]*** your question and show us the code you have, what works and what you need help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write a stopwatch function, like the one I have posted [here](https://superuser.com/a/611582/151431), and call it telling it to watch the process id of the command you're running (note that this assumes GNU `date`):

```
#!/bin/bash

stopwatch(){
    date1=`date +%s`; 
    while kill -0 $1 2>/dev/null; do 
        printf "Elapsed time: %s\r" "$(date -u --date @$((`date +%s` - $date1)) +%H:%M:%S)";
        sleep 0.1
    done
}

find /path/to/dir > output 2> error  &
stopwatch $!
```

Note that this approach means that if you kill the script with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the `find` process will keep running in the background. [Stéphane's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458101/22222) is a better idea.

Comment: That assumes GNU `date`. Note that `bash`'s `printf` has builtin support for timestamp formatting.

Comment: thanks dude it really works perfectly another thing can i put the pid of the script directly like stopwatch PID

Comment: @ammar yes, `$!` is a PID, it's the PID of the last process launched by n the background.

Comment: no i mean by PID is the PID of the whole script not the last command

Comment: @ammar this is precisely why I asked you to show us the code you had. So we don't do this sort of back and forth in the comments. I don't understand what you mean, nor why you would want it, but yes, you can give the script's PID (`$$`). But that will just keep running for ever until you kill the script. You might want to ask a new question, _showing your code_ and explaining what you need in more detail.

Comment: ok no problem i got your point and no need for providing my script because i just need the functionality of stop watch and you provided it professionally thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

With the `bash` shell, you could do something like:

```
elapse() (
  SECONDS=0
  while read -t1; (($? > 128)); do
    TZ=UTC0 printf >&2 '\rtime elapse %(%T)T' "$SECONDS"
  done
  echo >&2
)

{ long-running-command 4>&1 >&3 3>&- | elapse; } 3>&1
```

Comment: And, unlike mine, this will kill any child processes if you Ctrl+C out of the script, right?

Comment: `^C` sends SIGINT to the whole process group, so in yours like in mine, it should kill all processes spawned by the script.

Comment: That's what I would expect, but I tested with a `find &` sent to the background in the script, and Ctrl+C kills the script and the timer but not the `find`.

Comment: @terdon, oh yes, you're right, commands started with `&` ignore SIGINT.

Comment: @Isaac, no, elapse would eat what the command writes on its fd 4 (nothing as it's not meant to touch that). The writing end of the pipe is moved to the fd 4, while the original stdout is restored through the fd 3. The timing information is written on stderr as is customary for this kind of progress output.